# Can not run mongo command in terminal

Tags: mongodb, shell, terminal, command, installation

I installed mongoDB with a .tar in a certian directory and I can only run mongo in that directory if i use

`./mongo`

Otherwise if i try to just use

`mongo`

The terminal will tell me that it is not installed. What should I do?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path

Comment: I tried to do this and it did not work. I used - nano .bashrc

and added export PATH:my/path/

and it still does not work

Comment: Did you start the mongo server `mongod` ?

Comment: did you add the exact phrase "PATH:my/path" to your bashrc? Here's some useful info on paths in UNIX that might help give you some context for your problem: http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html

Answer (score 0):

Try, adding the following line to the .bashrc

```
alias mongod='path_to_mongodb/bin/mongod'
alias mongo='path_to_mongodb/bin/mongo'
```

Comment: i added the alias but now it says that there isn't a file there when there clearly is.